# Hash an ID to a Random x,y coordinate within a boundary square

Tags: hash

I  have a defined area (I know the x,y coordinates of each corner of the area). I need to hash an ID (int or char array) to an x,y point confined within that boundary area. The resulting hashed value i.e. x,y co-ordinates need to be unique to the ID and preferably I don't want the x,y points clustered all in one part of the square but rather evenly distributed over the square.

Any advice about how I can go about this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think you can guarantee uniqueness.  If you have `maxX*maxY+1` IDs, you will necessarily have two IDs at the same coordinate.

Second, to avoid clustering, use a cryptographically secure hash.

Third, to get x and y coordinates (roughly / pseudocode):

```
 hashResult = hash(ID)
 x = hashResult modulo maxX.
 y = ( hashResult div maxX) modulo maxY
```